# facing issue while populating/referencing the variable in shell

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have an input file which has data as shown below:

```
name,local_unit,region_unit
AAAAA,hour,cell
BBBBB,15min,cell
```

Here is my shell

```
#!/bin/bash

file_path='/home/vikrant_singh_rana/test_bq_file.csv'


{
    read
    while IFS=, read -r name local_unit region_unit
    do
        echo $name
        echo $local_unit
        echo $region_unit

        ingest_tablename=ABC_XYZ_$name
        echo $ingest_tablename
        aggr_tablename=ABC_XYZ_$name_$local_unit_$region_unit_aggregation
        echo $aggr_tablename

    done
} < $file_path
```

It is able to populate the table name for variable `ingest_tablename` and not for `aggr_tablename`

Output as shown below:

```
AAAAA
hour
cell
ABC_XYZ_AAAAA
ABC_XYZ_
BBBBB
15min
cell
ABC_XYZ_BBBB
ABC_XYZ_
```

Comment: Is that really the script you are running? Doesn't that give you a syntax error?

Comment: yeah.. Its running. I will paste output as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the underline `_` is a valid character in variable names, `ABC_XYZ_$name_$local_unit_$region_unit_aggregation` tries to expand variables called `$name_`, `$local_unit_` and `$region_unit_aggregation`. The first two are probably wrong. To stop that, put the variable names in question in braces, i.e.

```
aggr_tablename="ABC_XYZ_${name}_${local_unit}_$region_unit_aggregation"
```

(or  `aggr_tablename="ABC_XYZ_${name}_${local_unit}_${region_unit}_aggregation"` if that's what it should be.)

The quotes aren't strictly necessary in the assignment but otherwise a good idea.

FWIW, shellcheck.net tells of the problem, but sadly not how to solve it, it says:

> ^-- SC2154: name_ is referenced but not assigned (did you mean 'name'?).

Comment: perfect !.. a slight change mean a lot in Shell. Thank you

Comment: and how to reference this variable name in query.        bq query --format=pretty --use_legacy_sql=false 'select DATE FROM `test-project.test-dataset.$ingest_tablename`;'